# How can I resolve an interval (start- and end-value) to a logical matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I want to build a logical matrix with defined size (e.g. 3x5) out of a dataframe with a time-column and two columns with a start- and an end-value. In RL the matrix will have a very big number of rows and thousands of columns. A further goal is to plot a heatmap with the data (see example).

What is the most efficient way to get the logical matrix in R? (so the **step from »intervals_by_time« to   »data«**)
Column-names are not relevant in  »data«.

```r
library(magrittr)

intervals_by_time <- tibble::tibble(epoch = c(1, 2, 3), interval_start = c(1, 1, 5), interval_end = c(3, 5, 5))


data <- tibble::tibble(epoch = c(1, 2, 3),
                       pos_01 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), 
                       pos_02 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
                       pos_03 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
                       pos_04 = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
                       pos_05 = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
                       )

data_plot <- data %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = 2:6, names_to = "pos", values_to = "val")


ggplot2::ggplot(data = data_plot, ggplot2::aes(x = pos, y = epoch, fill = val)) +
  ggplot2::geom_tile()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: There are 5 columns because the minimum interval is 1 and the maximum is 5? If, for instance, `min(interval_*)` was 3 and `max(interval_*)` was 8 the output `data` would have 6 columns?

Comment: In general, yeah! In my special case I have a sequence of 1:n for the position. n is variable, so that i have in maximum n columns (+1 column for the timestamp / epoch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a vector of FALSE values, `template` and then for each row of the input fill in the TRUE values.

```
template <- rep(FALSE, max(intervals_by_time$interval_end))
repl <- function(x) replace(template, x[2]:x[3], TRUE)
m <- t(apply(intervals_by_time, 1, repl)); m
##       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
## [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
## [2,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
## [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

### Graphics

Try heatmap or for larger matrices try image.

```
heatmap(+m, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, revC = TRUE, col = 2:3, scale = "none")

nr <- nrow(m)
image(t(m[nr:1,]), useRaster = TRUE, axes = FALSE, col = 2:3)
```

[image: screenshot]

or use ggplot2 to give a balloon plot or tile plot

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(as.data.frame.table(m), aes(Var2, Var1, col = Freq)) + 
  geom_point(cex = 20) + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)

ggplot(as.data.frame.table(m), aes(Var2, Var1, fill = Freq)) + 
  geom_tile(col = "black") + 
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev)
```

[image: screenshot]

Another option is plot.matrix from the plot.matrix package.

```
library(plot.matrix)
plot(m, col = 2:3, mar = c(4, 4, 4, 4))
```

[image: screenshot]